# How to keep track of the purchased items in StoreKit?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have implemented an in-app purchase in my app that allows the user to use an advanced feature once (consumable product). How is it possible to track if the user have used this feature or not after the payment ?

**Example:**

The user have done the payment and suddently killed the app, he should be able to use the advanced feature after relaunching the app.

I do not want to use `UserDefaults` to track this. Does `StoreKit` provide any solution to that ?

Comment: Would you like Apple, Inc. to monitor every move you make as an IAP buyer?  If you want to know when the product was used for the first time, that's your business with your user.  And you have to tell them that their history of use is recorded in your privacy statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of purchase, you would verify the receipt with your server and while you are doing this, save the data you need in your own database.

See: [Validating Receipts with the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store)